# How to convert a string to a HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a Java Property file and there is a `KEY` as `ORDER`. So I retrieve the `VALUE` of that `KEY` using the `getProperty()` method after loading the property file like below.:

```
String s = prop.getProperty("ORDER");
```

then

```
s ="SALES:0,SALE_PRODUCTS:1,EXPENSES:2,EXPENSES_ITEMS:3";
```

I need to create a HashMap from above string. `SALES,SALE_PRODUCTS,EXPENSES,EXPENSES_ITEMS` should be `KEY` of HashMap  and `0,1,2,3,` should be `VALUE`s of `KEY`s.

If it's hard corded, it seems like below:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap  = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
myMap.put("SALES", 0);
myMap.put("SALE_PRODUCTS", 1);
myMap.put("EXPENSES", 2);
myMap.put("EXPENSES_ITEMS", 3);
```

Comment: If it really is for the given String, keep the hardcoded solution... If not please tell us what you have tried so far and what your problem is.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @pgras i have edited my post. i think now it's not complicated to understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representing key-value pairs to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768171/convert-string-representing-key-value-pairs-to-map)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use the [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method with the `,` separator to get the list of pairs. Iterate the pairs and use `split()` again with the `:` separator to get the key and value for each pair.

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String s = "SALES:0,SALE_PRODUCTS:1,EXPENSES:2,EXPENSES_ITEMS:3";
String[] pairs = s.split(",");
for (int i=0;i<pairs.length;i++) {
    String pair = pairs[i];
    String[] keyValue = pair.split(":");
    myMap.put(keyValue[0], Integer.valueOf(keyValue[1]));
}
```

Comment: using a foreach you can save a row! :)

Comment: the String.split() method link is broken

Comment: @KumarAnkit comma being a hard separator is one of the OP's assumptions or requirements. This answer, as could not be otherwise, builds on that.

Comment: what if your any key, value contains comma?

Comment: Wouldn't using an ObjectMapper be better and faster than this?

Answer (score 70):

You can do that with [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) [Splitter.MapSplitter](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html):

```
Map<String, String> properties = Splitter.on(",")
    .withKeyValueSeparator(":")
    .split(inputString);
```

Comment: Please note this returns an immutable list

Comment: @xilef and that is the best part of it!

Comment: It returns me a collection of key-value pairs whereas I want a HashMap

Comment: @Sankalp it returns a `Map` not key-value pairs.

Answer (score 30):

In one line :

```java
HashMap<String, Integer> map = (HashMap<String, Integer>) Arrays.asList(str.split(",")).stream().map(s -> s.split(":")).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e[0], e -> Integer.parseInt(e[1])));
```

*Details:*

1) Split entry pairs and convert string array to `List<String>` in order to use `java.lang.Collection.Stream` API from `Java 1.8`

```java
Arrays.asList(str.split(","))
```

2) Map the resulting string list `"key:value"` to a string array with [0] as key and [1] as value

```java
map(s -> s.split(":"))
```

3) Use `collect` terminal method from stream API to mutate

```java
collect(Collector<? super String, Object, Map<Object, Object>> collector)
```

4) Use the `Collectors.toMap()` static method which take two Function to perform mutation from input type to key and value type.

```java
toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)
```

where T is the input type, K the key type and U the value type.

5) Following lambda mutate `String` to `String` key and `String` to `Integer` value

```java
toMap(e -> e[0], e -> Integer.parseInt(e[1]))
```

**Enjoy the stream and lambda style with `Java 8`.** ***No more loops !***

Comment: I may get flagged but I gotta say, holy shit! I never knew Java was this powerful.

Comment: This "one line" will give nightmare to future maintainers

Comment: So simple and concise!!

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` (Maven repo link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core) like

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> mapFromString = new HashMap<>();
try {
    mapFromString = mapper.readValue(theStringToParse, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Exception launched while trying to parse String to Map.", e);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**USING JAVA 8:**

```
Map<String, String> headerMap = Arrays.stream(header.split(","))
                    .map(s -> s.split(":"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming no key contains either `','` or `':'`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(final String entry : s.split(",")) {
    final String[] parts = entry.split(":");
    assert(parts.length == 2) : "Invalid entry: " + entry;
    map.put(parts[0], new Integer(parts[1]));
}
```

Comment: what options can we use when we get a **,**

Answer (score 3):

You can also use JSONObject class from json.org to this will convert your HashMap to JSON string which is well formatted

Example:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("myNumber", 100);
map.put("myString", "String");

JSONObject json= new JSONObject(map);

String result= json.toString();

System.out.print(result);
```

result:

```
{'myNumber':100, 'myString':'String'}
```

Your can also get key from it like

```
System.out.print(json.get("myNumber"));
```

result:

```
100
```

Comment: OP wants the opposite of it:  HashMap from String!

Answer (score 2):

Use StringTokenizer to parse the string.

```
String s ="SALES:0,SALE_PRODUCTS:1,EXPENSES:2,EXPENSES_ITEMS:3";
    Map<String, Integer> lMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String [] array=st.nextToken().split(":");
        lMap.put(array[0], Integer.valueOf(array[1]));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to use split to do it:

```
 String[] elements = s.split(",");
 for(String s1: elements) {
     String[] keyValue = s1.split(":");
     myMap.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
 }
```

Nevertheless, myself I will go for guava based solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10514513/1356883

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 String s = "SALES:0,SALE_PRODUCTS:1,EXPENSES:2,EXPENSES_ITEMS:3";
    HashMap<String,Integer> hm =new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(String s1:s.split(",")){
       String[] s2 = s1.split(":");
        hm.put(s2[0], Integer.parseInt(s2[1]));
    }
```