# Convert string representing key-value pairs to Map

Tags: java, dictionary

How can I convert a String into a Map:

```
Map m = convert("A=4 H=X PO=87"); // What's convert?
System.err.println(m.getClass().getSimpleName()+m);
```

Expected output:

```
HashMap{A=4, H=X, PO=87}
```

Comment: Really? The 5 lines of code it would take was too much?

Comment: I think this is not a regular problem and you have to write your own converter. Using regular expressions it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: @BrianRoach 50 lines. It's Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to HashMap JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514473/string-to-hashmap-java)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. The Google Guava library provides the [`Splitter` class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

Here's how you can use it along with some test code:

```
package com.sandbox;

import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Test
    public void testQuestionInput() {
        Map<String, String> map = splitToMap("A=4 H=X PO=87");
        assertEquals("4", map.get("A"));
        assertEquals("X", map.get("H"));
        assertEquals("87", map.get("PO"));
    }

    private Map<String, String> splitToMap(String in) {
        return Splitter.on(" ").withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(in);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, it does answer the question (even including the library requirement) so .. +1. Although I'm not entirely sure the dependency is justified if *just* for this task.

Comment: There will be `IllegalArgumentException` when the string passed into the `splitToMap` is either an empty string `""` or a string with irregular structure like `"A=4=3"`.

Comment: Also `IllegalArgumentException` for trailing separator, e.g. `"A=3 B=4 "`

Comment: [Splitter.MapSplitter (Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 19.0 API)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Also, IndexOutOfBoundsException for when the string contains a `,`.

Answer (score 31):

Java 8 to the rescue!

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String, String> result = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
    .map(s -> s.split("="))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        a -> a[0],  //key
        a -> a[1]   //value
    ));
```

NOTE: Assuming no duplicates. Otherwise look into the 3rd 'mergeFunction' argument.

Comment: NOTE: The code "Collectors." is not needed but my answer has been edited and approved by the community. Democracy won, I lost...

Comment: My IDE gives following message if the code "Collectors" is not used  
`The method toMap((<no type> a) -> {}, (<no type> a) -> {}) is undefined`,



what IDE you use? @Gevorg

Comment: The one and only: IntelliJ IDEA! Are you using the 'static import' as shown in the answer?

Comment: I like this answer, because I was able to rewrite it in Kotlin like this: `input.split(" ").map { it.split("=") }.associate { Pair(it[0], it[1]) }`, thus rendering Guava unnecessary.

Comment: @arekolek Hi arekolek, note that there is no Guava in the answer. It's pure Java 8.

Comment: @Gevorg Sorry for the confusion, I was referring to the other answer and the fact that I couldn't use Java 8, but can use Guava or Kotlin. I see I didn't make this clear in my comment.

Answer (score 23):

You don't need a library to do that. You just need to use StringTokenizer or [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and iterate over the tokens to fill the map.

The import of the library plus its settings would be almost as big as the three lines of code needed to do it yourself. For example :

```
public static Map<String, String> convert(String str) {
    String[] tokens = str.split(" |=");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i=0; i<tokens.length-1; ) map.put(tokens[i++], tokens[i++]);
    return map;
}
```

Note that in real life, the validation of the tokens and the string, highly coupled with your business requirement, would probably be more important than the code you see here.

Comment: +1 Yes. Such a method can then be shared across to make it look like a library.

Comment: You don't need a library to do most things.  Where do you draw the line?

Comment: @tieTYT At the language, which is why I don't use Java anymore :D

Comment: @user166390 - Because you left SO and now work as a lumberjack?

Answer (score 7):

```
public static Map<String, String> splitToMap(String source, String entriesSeparator, String keyValueSeparator) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] entries = source.split(entriesSeparator);
    for (String entry : entries) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(entry) && entry.contains(keyValueSeparator)) {
            String[] keyValue = entry.split(keyValueSeparator);
            map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

And now you can use it for different types of entries/key-values separators, just like this

```
Map<String, String> responseMap = splitToMap(response, " ", "=");
```

Comment: This worked great for me! I had a comma-delimited list so just passed `(response, ", ", "=")`. However, some of my keys had no value, so I'd get an indexOutOfBoundsException on keyValue[1]. This was fixed with
`map.put(keyValue[0], (keyValue.length > 1 ? keyValue[1] : ""));`

Comment: This is a good method. If your separator has a character like |, then you need to pass "\\|" to escape it instead of just "|" which will not work!

Answer (score 4):

split String by " ", then split each item by "=" and put pairs into map. Why would you need "library" for such elementary thing?

Comment: Usually I agree (so +1), but I happen to use Guava already, so using that one is simpler in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose another way for specific case when you have key-value pairs in different lines: to use Java's built-in `Properties` class:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new StringReader(s));
```

### BENEFITS:

- short
- for any Java version
- gives you a ready-to-use Map<Object, Object> also supplying handy `String props.getProperty(String)` method
- `StringReader` has built-in 8k buffer (you may adjust buffering on mega input)
- steady against different newline characters
- you may base on defaults Map with `new Properties(defaultsMap)`

### WARNINGS (could be virtue or vice):

- has special parsing rules for '.properties' format (you may want to peek inside `Properties` class to learn more):

  - trims spaces/tabs from keys/values
  - has special-meaning characters:

    - `!`,`#` at beginning of line is comment
    - `=` or `:` is key-value separator
    - `\` is used as escape character for unicode/special chars. For example, you may want to prepare your string with `s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\");`
- resulting Map is based on `HashTable` having synchronization unneeded in most cases

Answer (score 0):

```
private HashMap<String, String> convert(String str) {
    String[] tokens = str.split("&");
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
    {
        String[] strings = tokens[i].split("=");
        if(strings.length==2)
         map.put(strings[0], strings[1].replaceAll("%2C", ","));
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When posting code, please also try to explain the main parts of the code, so that the OP can also understand it.

Answer (score -1):

```
String elementType = StringUtility.substringBetween(elementValue.getElementType(), "{", "}");
Map<String, String>  eleTypeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(elementType, ",");
while(token.hasMoreElements()){
    String str = token.nextToken();
    StringTokenizer furtherToken = new StringTokenizer(str,"=");
    while(furtherToken.hasMoreTokens()){
        eleTypeMap.put(furtherToken.nextToken(), furtherToken.nextToken());
    }
}
```