# Convert String to List<Map<String, String>>> for tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I need to convert a `String` to `List<Map<String, String>>>` for pass JUnit Test. I have this:

```
String userAttributes = "[{name=test, cp=458999, lastname=test2}]";
```

That i want is in the tests (Mockito) change a call to a server with this values, something like this:

```
Mockito.when(template.search(Mockito.anyString, new AttributesMapper()).thenReturn(attributes);
```

I need `List<Map<String, String>>>` for do this:

```
user.setUserName(attributes.get("name"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert String into Hashmap in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485964/how-to-convert-string-into-hashmap-in-java)

Comment: Provide an answer instead of editing your question to add a SOLUTION section.

Comment: Can you say if given ansvers solve your problem or say what's wrong are with them? Respond on answers helps in future to precise the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex or split by special char. First remove parentheses from beginning and end. After that you can split it by `,` and `=` to collect strings to map.

```java
String userAttributes = "[{name=test, cp=458999, lastname=test2}]";

List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(userAttributes
      .replace("[{","").replace("}]","")
      .split(", "));
Map<String, String> collect = strings.stream()
      .map(s -> s.split("="))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));

System.out.println(collect.get("name"));
```

Other approach with `Pattern`

```java
Map<String, String> collect = Pattern.compile(",")
        .splitAsStream(userAttributes
                .replace("[{","").replace("}]",""))
        .map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

Or if you really wants use `List<Map<String, String>>>`. But after that you can not do this `user.setUserName(attributes.get("name"));`

```java
List<Map<String, String>> maps = strings.stream()
      .map(s -> s.split("="))
      .map(s -> Map.of(s[0], s[1]))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(maps);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    String userAttributes = "[{name=test, cp=458999, lastname=test2}]";
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(userAttributes,",");
    List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()){
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer2 = new StringTokenizer((String)stringTokenizer.nextElement(),"=");
        while(stringTokenizer2.hasMoreElements()){
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put( ((String)stringTokenizer2.nextElement()),((String)stringTokenizer2.nextElement()) );
            list.add(map);
        }
    }

    System.err.println(list.toString());
```

Comment: You do not remove "[{" and "}]"

Comment: it is not required if you use StringTokenizer .

Comment: Run this code and: `[{[{name=test}, { cp=458999}, { lastname=test2}]}]`

Comment: Or `list.stream().forEach(m -> System.out.println(m.entrySet()));` you get key "{name" , " cp", " lastname"