# Java 8: How to convert String to Map<String,String>?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map:

```
Map<String, String> utilMap = new HashMap();
utilMap.put("1","1");
utilMap.put("2","2");
utilMap.put("3","3");
utilMap.put("4","4");
```

I converted it to a String:

```
String utilMapString = utilMap
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> e.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
Out put: 1=1,2=2,3=3,4=4,5=5
```

How to convert utilMapString to Map  in Java8? Who can help me with?

Comment: Take a look at the flatMap's documentation.

Comment: You can't, because if you replace `utilMap.put("2","2");` with `utilMap.put(",=",",=,=");`, then you end up with `1=1,,==,=,=,3=3,4=4,5=5`, and that is irreversible.

Comment: If I use Map <Long, Long> then I can not @Andreas

Comment: @PhuongLinh But your question is using `Map<String, String>`

Comment: @Andreas I also can flexibly switch to HashMap <Long, Long> form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representing key-value pairs to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768171/convert-string-representing-key-value-pairs-to-map)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Split the string by `,` to get individual map entries. Then split them by `=` to get the key and the value.

```
Map<String, String> reconstructedUtilMap = Arrays.stream(utilMapString.split(","))
            .map(s -> s.split("="))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

*Note:* As pointed out by [Andreas@ in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695410/java-8-how-to-convert-string-to-mapstring-string/52695467#comment92317315_52695410), this is not a reliable way to convert between a map and a string

**EDIT**:
Thanks to Holger for this suggestion.

Use `s.split("=", 2)` to ensure that the array is never larger than two elements. This will be useful to not lose the contents (when the value has `=`)

*Example:* when the input string is `"a=1,b=2,c=3=44=5555"`
you will get `{a=1, b=2, c=3=44=5555}`

Earlier (just using `s.split("=")`) will give 
`{a=1, b=2, c=3}`

Comment: Comma is not a regex special character, so no need to escape it.

Comment: Use `s.split("=", 2)` to ensure that the array is never larger than two elements. While we can’t fix ambiguous `=` characters, we can prevent losing contents when there are more of them.

Comment: If this is the case `a=1,b=` the above code will throw NullPointerException how we can address the null pointer issue `Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1])`

Comment: Not NullPointerException it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option which streams a list of `1=1` etc. terms into a map.

```
String input = "1=1,2=2,3=3,4=4,5=5";
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.asList(input.split(",")).stream().collect(
             Collectors.toMap(x -> x.replaceAll("=\\d+$", ""),
                 x -> x.replaceAll("^\\d+=", "")));
System.out.println(Collections.singletonList(map));

[{1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=5}]
```

Comment: Why not `x.replaceFirst("=.*", "")` and `x.replaceFirst(".*=", "")`? Still heavy compared to `x.substring(0, x.indexOf('='))` and `x.substring(x.indexOf('=')+1)`, but not trying to bend `replaceAll`’s behavior towards `replaceFirst` behavior via regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a map from String you can it with below way:

```
Map<String, String> newMap = Stream.of(utilMapString.split("\\,"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.toString().split("=")[0], t -> t.toString().split("=")[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence may contain values with the same key - use

```
Map<String, String> skipDuplicatesMap = Stream.of("1=1,2=2,3=3,4=4,5=5".split(",")).
            map(el -> el.split("=")).
            collect(toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> arr[1], (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue));
```