# Converting string to Map<Integer,String> in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve the below using Java 8. I don't know **how to get that counter as the key**

```
String str = "abcd";

Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();

String[] strings = str.split("");

int count =0;
for(String s:strings){
    map.put(count++, s);// I want the counter as the key
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8: How to convert String to Map<String,String>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695410/java-8-how-to-convert-string-to-mapstring-string)

Comment: You are preferably looking for a `Map<Integer, Character>` accessing which again is mostly accessible via `String.charAt`. What's the use case around building this Map if you could share the details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IntStream` to get this thing done. Use the integer value as the key, and the relevant value in the string array at that index as the value of the map.

```
Map<Integer, String> counterToStr = IntStream.range(0, strings.length)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> strings[i]));
```

Another alternative that obviates the need of `split` would be,

```
Map<Integer, String> counterToStr = IntStream.range(0, strings.length)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> str.charAt(i) + ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write like

```
    String str = "abcd";
    Map<Integer, Character> map = IntStream.range(0, str.length()).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), pos -> str.charAt(pos)));
```

No need to split the String with `String[] strings = str.split("");` A simple one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without the counter as:

```
String str = "abcd";
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
String[] strings = str.split("");
for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++) {
    map.put(i, strings[i]);
}
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+" "+v));
```

*Another way around*, credit [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)

```
for(String s: strings) {
     map.put(map.size(), s);
 }
```

Comment: or `for(String s: strings) map.put(map.size(), s);`

Comment: @Holger , yeah it will work,  i added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solution: some of them would be  like this:

```
Map<Integer,Character> map = new HashMap<>();

AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0); 
map = str.chars()
            .mapToObj(i->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(atomicInteger.getAndAdd(1),(char)i))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

or even use simple `forEach`

```
int count =0;
for (Character c:str.toCharArray()) {
  map.putIfAbsent(count++,c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will help you to create a linked hash map. The keys are characters and the values are the count of each character in the string.

```
 String str = "preethi";

 Map<Character, Integer> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>();

 str.chars().mapToObj(x -> (char)x).forEach(ch -> {
          lhm.put(ch, lhm.get(ch) != null ? lhm.get(ch) + 1: 1);
 });
```

[image]