# What is difference between isEmpty() and size() for hashmap if used under if condition?

Tags: java

I have to deal with `NullPointerException` which is occurring on `Hashmap`. Shall I use `map.isEmpty()` or (`map.size() > 0`) inside `if` condition?

Which one is better?

Comment: They're the same (well, actually, they're opposites of each other).  But probably neither will prevent your null pointer exception.

Comment: How can I nullify Null pointer exception incase such case?

Comment: Well, _assuming_ your null pointer exception is happening because your `Map` is null, you should check whether your `Map` is null.  But maybe the exception is happening for some other reason - it's impossible to tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 6):

Here are the [implementations](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) for `size()` and `isEmpty()` in the `HashMap` class:

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}
```

So, `HashMap#isEmpty()` just checks the same `size` variable which `size()` returns.  It is mainly just a convenience method.  One reason why you might want to use `isEmpty()` over manually comparing the size is that the former makes it clearer what your code is actually checking.

Comment: +1, but `isEmpty()` isn't necessarily *just* a convenience method: it's specified by `java.util.Map`, and in at least one implementation of that interface (namely [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)) it's significantly faster than `size()`.

Comment: @ruakh Good stuff, I did not know this.

Comment: If there is no key-value pair in hashmap ,is there any case/chance that size() would return non zero value?

Comment: @RadhickaPardessi The size should never go negative AFAIK.

Comment: @ruakh I expected this to be the case for `LinkedList`, but surprisingly, it's not. It just inherits the [`AbstractCollection` implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java).

Comment: @jpmc26: Yeah, `java.util.LinkedList` keeps its size in a field for that purpose. I think the only JDK collections that compute their size dynamically are those optimized for concurrency, such as `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. Most of these define `isEmpty()` in a more-optimal way than `size()`; the only exception I see offhand is `ConcurrentHashMap`, which *could* exit early but *doesn't*. (I haven't looked exhaustively though the JDK, though, and I haven't even glanced at non-JDK collections such as those provided by Guava.)

Answer (score 5):

First do the null check on `Map` object and then `Empty` check to avoid `NullPointerException`

```
if(map != null && !map.isEmpty())
```

Comment: I got rid of my NullPointerException after using above if condition. Thnaks for the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

`map.size()` is *O(1)* , while complexity of `map.isEmpty()` is also the same, so basically no difference between them from point of complexity and execution.

If you carefully look at

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}
```

It is doing nothing but returning **size==0**;

Other reasons to prefer `.isEmpty()` over `.size()` can be:

1. it is more expressive (the code is easier to read and to maintain)

   ---

Just FYI, `map.size()` has various advantages over map.isEmpty() when it comes to deal with collection, like you can do below operation just by `map.size()` not by later.

```
String str = "abcd";
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
String[] strings = str.split("");
for(String s: strings) {
     map.put(map.size(), s);
 }
```

**Reference**: [Converting string to Map<Integer,String> in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779842/converting-string-to-mapinteger-string-in-java-8/54780138#54780138)

Comment: check answer again, i missed it. both are actually same. I thought of general collection :/

Comment: Ok, just not faster by any orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

`map.size() == 0` is equal to `map.isEmpty()`. E.g. IntelliJ IDEA has inspection to always use `isEmpty()` instead of `size() == 0`.