# Transforming JAVA stream throws IllegalStateException: Duplicate key

Tags: java, java-stream

Some time ago this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695410/java-8-how-to-convert-string-to-mapstring-string/52695467) was asked:

Input String: utilMapString = "1=1,2=2,3=3,4=4,5=5"

```
Map<String, String> reconstructedUtilMap = Arrays.stream(utilMapString.split(","))
            .map(s -> s.split("="))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

If I change the input to "101|Google,102|Amazon" and perform same transformation, code throws IllegalStateException: Duplicate key

```
Map<String, String> reconstructedUtilMap = Arrays.stream(utilMapString.split(","))
                .map(s -> s.split("|", 2))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

Can somebody please explain the exact difference between the two set of operation.

Comment: Hint: the result of `"101|Google,102|Amazon".split("|")` isn't what I think you expect it to be

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796160

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonSkeet, got what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the pipe character in your second `split()` call. Like this:

```
Map<String, String> reconstructedUtilMap = Arrays.stream("101|Google,102|Amazon" .split(","))
                .map(s -> s.split("\\|"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```