# Android save hashmap to SharedPreferences

Tags: android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I have a Recyclerview which has checkboxes which when clicked saves the status of checkboxes  and their position in the Recyclerview layout in the hashmap.I want to send the hashmap to another activity.Is it possible to save hashmap to SharedPreferences.

Code:

```
if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                        boolean check=true;
                        clicked_position=getAdapterPosition();
                        i=new Integer(clicked_position);
                       hashMap.put(i, check);}
 if(hashMap!=null){
                            SharedPreferences selectedplaces=context.getSharedPreferences("selectedplaces",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=selectedplaces.edit();

                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your map to `JSON` and read it back from `String` when necessary.

Here is how to convert it to JSON: 
[How to convert HashMap to json Array in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402321/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-array-in-android)

And here is how to parse it back to `HashMap`:
[Convert a JSON String to a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap)

[EDIT] If keys are not of `String` format this as well can be easily achieved with `GSON` library:

```
        Map<Integer, Boolean> oldMap = new HashMap<>();
        oldMap.put(1, true);
        oldMap.put(2, false);

        Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Boolean>>() { }.getType();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        String json = gson.toJson(oldMap, typeOfHashMap);
        System.out.println(json);
        Map<Integer, Boolean> newMap = gson.fromJson(json, typeOfHashMap);
        System.out.println(newMap.get(1));
        System.out.println(newMap.get(2));
```

Just add `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'` to your build.gradle

Comment: I checked the link.It is said the key and value must be string.But the key is Integer object and value is Boolean in my Hashmap

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                            boolean check=true;
                            clicked_position=getAdapterPosition();
                            i=new Integer(clicked_position);
                           hashMap.put(i, check);}
     if(hashMap!=null){
                                SharedPreferences selectedplaces=context.getSharedPreferences("selectedplaces",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=selectedplaces.edit();
                                editor.put("key",hashMap.toString());
                                editor.commit;
                            }
```

> and finally you can convert your SharePreferences to HashMap. 
>   [String to HashMap JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514473/string-to-hashmap-java)