# Convert/Deserialise String to HashMap

Tags: java, string, serialization, hashmap, deserialization

I am struggling to deserialize a string into HashMap. My string looks like this:

`String str = "{key=qwerty, value=somestring}";`

I have tried Jackson to convert it back to HashMap but Jackson works on JSON so it requires me to have double-quotes. Is there a way to do it without converting the string to JSON format?

Comment: Unlikely, as JSON is only supported because it's a standard format.  Writing a parser for this wouldn't take much time though.

Comment: You could write a parser fairly easily, but you would need two know how an equals sign, a comma or a closing brace is represented in a string in this format. Do you have that information?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514473/string-to-hashmap-java/10514517